# Connect Language Tool with TexStudio on Mac

Tags: texstudio

I would like use LanguageTool in my TeXstudio distribution in order to check my grammar. I am using Mac OS X El Capitan, TeXstudio 2.11.0 and LanguageTool 3.2.

The Languagetool works as standalone or as a server. I've received following when I enter `http://localhost:8081/?language=en-US&text=my+texd` in the browser.

`<matches software="LanguageTool" version="3.2" buildDate="2015-12-29 10:24">
<language shortname="en-US" name="English (US)"/>
<error fromy="0" fromx="0" toy="0" tox="2" ruleId="UPPERCASE_SENTENCE_START" msg="This sentence does not start with an uppercase letter" replacements="My" context="my texd" contextoffset="0" offset="0" errorlength="2" category="Capitalization" locqualityissuetype="typographical"/>
<error fromy="0" fromx="3" toy="0" tox="7" ruleId="MORFOLOGIK_RULE_EN_US" msg="Possible spelling mistake found" replacements="text#tend#Ted#TeX#ted#teed#Tex" context="my texd" contextoffset="3" offset="3" errorlength="4" category="Possible Typo" locqualityissuetype="misspelling"/>
</matches>`

However, it doesn't work in TexStudio, I don't see any underlining of text for LT example quote "this is a example". Please, see the setting in figure. Any suggestions?

[image]

P.S: the field 'LT arguments' is empty.